# ¿ Como ejecutar un .jar para envió JSON mediante una tarea programada o un Job sql?

Tags: java, json, windows, batch

Veran, estoy intentando programar la ejecución periódica de un envió de tramas JSON, para esto tengo un programa .jar (spring boot) que realiza el envió, al ejecutarlo dándole doble click o mediante un .bat ejecuta sin problemas, sin embargo cuando intento ejecutarlo por el programador de tareas de windows o por un JOB sql seteado tipo operating system `CMD` las tareas terminan correctamente pero no ejecuta el .jar, incluso probe ejecutando el bat por el programador de tareas y jobs, pero igual no me ejecuta el jar, lo que me lleva a mi pregunta ¿como podría programar la ejecución periódica de este .jar en wnidows 10 o windows server 2016.?
 basicamente tengo dentro del .bat el codigo:

```
start C:\jar\export.jar -jar

exit
```

Comment: probablemente sea porque esta en un -jar, prueba a migrarlo a  `.bat` y luego  probado con Programador de Tareas --> Crear Tarea básicas --> Iniciar un programa y subes tu script.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con

> java -jar "C:\path_to_jar_file\myjarfile.jar"

o

> start javaw -jar "C:\path_to_jar_file\myjarfile.jar"

en tu archivo .bat